# Fraction of differential equation solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider that the functions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions to a first order system of differential equations, and define $y(t)$ such as:

$$y(t)=\frac{v(t)}{v(t)+u(t)}$$

$u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions to the following system of ODE:

$$u'(t)=b(u+v)-\mu_1u-\beta\frac{uv}{u+v}$$
and
$$v'(t)=-\mu_2v+\beta\frac{uv}{u+v}$$

I tried to differentiate $y(t)$ which after using the chain rule gives that $y'(t)={y^2(t)}\cdot (v/u)'$. I have absolutely no idea how I can go on from here.
I also tried with partial integration, but this did not give anything either, anybody knows if this is some kind of special problem, and therefore has a very special solution?

Comment: What do you want to know ?

Comment: Just basically how to find y(t)

Comment: Your $y'(t)$ should be $y'(t)=-y^2(t)(u/v)'$, not $(v/u)'$.

Comment: But does that make a difference? I am still not able to find y(t)

Comment: $y(t)$ in terms of what ? If it's $u$ and $v$, you already have it :-) If in terms of the constants, substituting $u'$ and $v'$ in the preceding DE, I found $(1/y)'=\frac{b-(\mu_1-\mu_2+\beta-b)u}{v}$, don't know if this helps...

Comment: Yes, but I dont have u or v, thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with
$$y' = \frac{v'(v+u) - v(v'+u')}{(v+u)^2} = y^2\, \frac{v'u - vu'}{v^2}\, .$$
We substitute the expressions of $u'$, $v'$ in terms of $u$, $v$, so that
$$
\frac{v'u - vu'}{v^2} = -b - (b - \mu_1 + \mu_2)\frac{u}{v} + \beta\frac{u}{u+v} + \beta\frac{u^2}{v^2}\frac{v}{u+v} \, .
$$
Now, let us make the substitutions $\frac{v}{u+v} = y = 1-\frac{u}{u+v}$ and $\frac{u}{v} = \frac{1}{y}-1$ to obtain the [Bernoulli ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) -- a particular type of [Riccati ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) -- satisfied by $y$:
$$
y' = (\beta-b-\mu_2+\mu_1)y + (-\beta + \mu_2-\mu_1)y^2 .
$$
The solutions are
$$
y(t) = \frac{\beta-b-\mu_2+\mu_1}{\beta-\mu_2+\mu_1 - c_2 e^{-t(\beta-b-\mu_2+\mu_1)}} \, .
$$
In the case $\mu_1 = \mu_2$, one can proceed differently. Indeed, rewriting the initial system in terms of $u$ and $w = u+v$ gives straightforwardly $w(t) = c_1 e^{t(b-\mu)}$. Then, one solves a Riccati equation to obtain $u$. Finally, $y = 1-u/w$ gives $y(t) = (\beta-b)/(\beta - c_2 e^{-t(\beta-b)})$, which is consistent with the previous result.

Comment: Could you explain your substitution a little more detailed, what do you mean by "with the substitution of u', v' ". I did not understand that, sorry

Comment: Also, it should be y'(t)=y^2(t)*(u/v)', not with the minus in front of it I think.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I didn't know about the class of Riccati equations at all. Are there other kind of classes and equation like the Riccati equations that are good to know?

Comment: Isn't this also a Bernoulli equation?

Comment: Yes, since the linear term in the Ricatti-eq is zero!

Comment: @JonathanKiersch The following [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToODEs.html) directs to a list of such typical ODEs.